# ImageButton in an HorizontalSrollView have a frame

Tags: android

I have this Layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/card_images_horizontalscroll"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:scrollbars="none"
   android:visibility="invisible"
   >


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/card_images_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

     <ImageButton 
      android:id="@+id/card_image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:background="@drawable/icona"
      android:
     />


    </LinearLayout>




  </HorizontalScrollView>
```

But I meet this issues: the image are enclose by a frame which I don't want, what's wrong?!

Like this:
[image]

Thanks so much!

I tried to change XML with this runtime code but I have the same issues:

```
b = new ImageButton(this);
            b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            b.startAnimation(alpha_animation);
            b.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

I tried also to follow the suggestion for change ImageButton in Button, but can I set at runtime the image source?

Comment: I find the problem: adding b.setPadding(0,0,0,0); all is right.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the image to the ImageButton with:

`android:src="@drawable/icona"`

and then set the background to null like this:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `ImageButton` with a `Button` with the background you want:

```
<Button 
  android:id="@+id/card_image"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:background="@drawable/icona"/>
```

Comment: How can I set at runtime the image source of a button? I have just a Bitmap.Thanks

Comment: You can call Button's setBackgroundDrawable() and pass to it a BitmapDrawable constructed passing in your Bitmap

Comment: Thanks!Can I use selector for an simple Button?